# How do you save a complex regex for multiple reuse in sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

In using `sed`, I often create rather complicated and intricate regexes that I need to match twice in a file.  Is there a way for me to save this regex and just reference it twice?

Maybe something that looks like this?

```
sed ' complicated_regex=/^(([a-f0-9]{32})+([a-zA-Z0-9=]{{$i}})?)+$/
s/complicated_regex:complicated_regex/simple-output/
' my_file
```

Update: An answer has presented the solution of using a bash variable.  This doesn't work.  Given a `test.txt`.

```
#test.txt
foo bar
bar foo
```

And the script

```
#!/bin/bash

VALUE='foo \([a-z]\+\)'

sed 's/"${VALUE}"/foo happy \1/' test.txt
```

This should produce the output

```
foo happy bar
bar foo
```

But instead I get the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: If you use Perl, you can reference previous parts of the expression within the expression: `perl -pe 's/^(([a-f0-9]{32})+([a-zA-Z0-9=]{{$i}})?)+:\1$/simple_output/' my_file`

Comment: When you find something too complicated for sed, don't hesitate to go for awk or perl.

Comment: @Cory: Your example works fine, if you get its syntax right. You have the "$variable" still enclosed in 'single-quotes' which hides it from the shell expansion you expect... it should be `sed 's/'"${VALUE}"'/foo happy \1/' test.txt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use shell variables:

```bash
complicated_regex='(([a-f0-9]{32})+([a-zA-Z0-9=]{{$i}})?)+'
sed s/^"$complicated_regex":"$complicated_regex"\$/'simple-output'/ my_file
```

I'm not sure about what you meant by `$i`, but you might need to put it outside single quotes:

```bash
complicated_regex='(([a-f0-9]{32})+([a-zA-Z0-9=]{{'"$i"'}})?)+'
```

Comment: Of course this works only if the `sed` command is invoked from the shell, but there is a similar solution with almost all programming languages. (And I don't think it's possible to use variables within `sed`.)

Comment: Hrm.  Trying this, backreferences appear to be broken.  `s/$complicated_regex/\1/` gives an error saying that is an invalid reference.

Comment: Ah, maybe my fault, I'm used to zsh variable substitutions. See updated answer.

Comment: You'll have to remove the anchors from the variable and put them in the sed script: `sed "s/^${complicated_regex}:${complicated_regex}\$/simple-output/" my_file`

Comment: Duh! Yes, I forgot to check that I was provided a valid regex concatenation :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to drop in a shell variable value to `sed` and not worry about how your backslash-escaping will need to change for the rest of your `sed` script, is to stuff everything into single quotes *except* the variable, and put that in double quotes.

All of the following code examples assume: `VALUE='foo \([a-z]\+\)'`

The following **broken** code fails because the variable `VALUE` isn't expanded:

```
sed 's/"${VALUE}"/foo happy \1/' test.txt
```

The following **broken** code fails because the backslash on `\1` gets eaten by the shell (because it's in double quotes rather than single quotes) before `sed` ever sees it:

```
sed "s/${VALUE}/foo happy \1/" test.txt
```

**The following code works as expected:**

```
sed 's/'"${VALUE}"'/foo happy \1/' test.txt
```

Tho following code also works:

```
sed "s/${VALUE}/foo happy \\1/" test.txt
```

So does the following:

```
sed s/"${VALUE}"/foo\ happy\ \\1/ test.txt
```

But why get complicated?  Single quotes around a `sed` script make everything much clearer, especially for the non-shell-scripting-gurus reading your code.  My favored way is, again, to drop out of single quotes to double quotes just for the variable expansion and jump right back to single quotes:

```
sed 's/'"${VALUE}"'/foo happy \1/' test.txt
```